# Slow mongodb query with low number of documents scanned

Tags: mongodb

I have a replica set of 3 MongoDB instances. The instances have 8GB of RAM and Dual Core 2.27 GHz CPUs. All instances are running version 2.2.2 (I saw the same behavior from 2.0.1).

Here's my issue: Our primary instance (master of the replica set) recently acquired the habit of crawling to 100% CPU every 2 days. Tracking down the cause, I decided to run the MongoDB profiler. I found hundreds of extremely slow queries. Here is an example:

```
> db.system.profile.find()
{ 
    "ts" : ISODate("2012-12-16T20:31:39.078Z"), 
    "op" : "command", 
    "ns" : "stylesaint.$cmd", 
    "command" : { 
        "count" : "tears", 
        "query" : { 
            "_id" : { "$gt" : ObjectId("50cdeadeaf58d3de96000294") }, 
            "active" : true, 
            "is_image_processed" : true, 
            "hidden_from_feed" : false, 
            "hidden_from_public_feeds" : false
        }, 
        "fields" : null 
    }, 
    "ntoreturn" : 1, 
    "responseLength" : 48, 
    "millis" : 13930, 
    "client" : "#########"
}
```

From what I've read about mongodb, the natural next step in these situations is to try explain()ing those queries. However, explain() does not explain the slowness of the query:

```
> db.tears.find({ "_id" : { "$gt" : ObjectId("50cdeadeaf58d3de96000294") }, "active" : true, "is_image_processed" : true, "hidden_from_feed" : false, "hidden_from_public_feeds" : false }).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor id",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 4,
    "nscannedObjects" : 5,
    "nscanned" : 5,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 23,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 25,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : { 
        "_id" : [ 
            [ 
                ObjectId("50cdeadeaf58d3de96000294"), 
                ObjectId("ffffffffffffffffffffffff")
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "#########"
}
```

Scanning 5 documents should not take 13 seconds. Something else is going on that is slowing down the query. Maybe some other query is starving the server's resources? However, I don't know where to look. Any advice you can offer is appreciated.

**MongoDB Logs**

I couldn't find any warnings in the startup process:

```
***** SERVER RESTARTED *****


Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=...
Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.2, pdfile version 4.5
Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [initandlisten] git version: ...   
Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [initandlisten] build info: Linux 2.6.21.7-2 ...
Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/data/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log", replSet: "...", rest: "true" }
Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/mongodb/journal
Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port ...
Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port ...
Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [initandlisten] connection accepted from ...
Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [conn1] end connection ... (0 connections now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [initandlisten] connection accepted from ... #2 (1 connection now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [rsStart] replSet I am ...
Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [rsStart] replSet STARTUP2
Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [rsHealthPoll] replSet member ... is up
Sun Dec 16 21:02:56 [rsHealthPoll] replSet member ... is now in state SECONDARY
Sun Dec 16 21:02:57 [initandlisten] connection accepted from ... #3 (2 connections now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:02:57 [rsSync] replSet SECONDARY
Sun Dec 16 21:02:58 [initandlisten] connection accepted from ... #4 (3 connections now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:02:58 [initandlisten] connection accepted from ... #5 (4 connections now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:02:58 [conn5] end connection ... (3 connections now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:02:58 [rsHealthPoll] replSet member ... is up
Sun Dec 16 21:02:58 [rsHealthPoll] replSet member ... is now in state PRIMARY
Sun Dec 16 21:02:59 [initandlisten] connection accepted from ... #6 (4 connections now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:03:00 [initandlisten] connection accepted from ... #7 (5 connections now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:03:02 [conn7] end connection ... (4 connections now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:03:03 [rsBackgroundSync] replSet syncing to: ...
Sun Dec 16 21:03:04 [rsSyncNotifier] replset setting oplog notifier to ...
Sun Dec 16 21:03:06 [conn2] end connection ... (3 connections now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:03:06 [initandlisten] connection accepted from ... #8 (4 connections now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:03:08 [initandlisten] connection accepted from ... #9 (5 connections now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:03:13 [initandlisten] connection accepted from ... #10 (6 connections now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:03:13 [conn10] end connection ... (5 connections now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:03:13 [initandlisten] connection accepted from ... #11 (6 connections now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:03:15 [conn3] end connection ... (5 connections now open)
Sun Dec 16 21:03:16 [rsHealthPoll] replSet member .... is now in state SECONDARY
Sun Dec 16 21:03:16 [rsMgr] replSet info electSelf 1
Sun Dec 16 21:03:16 [rsMgr] replSet PRIMARY
```

**Re: Request for more info**

At the moment, MongoDB is functioning normally; there are no queries above 100ms. As soon as 100% CPU happens again, I'll post more info about system resources.

Comment: What do you mean with your "primary instance"? The master of a replicated mondodb?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I've updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think the queries are probably a red herring. Are you running these servers under a NUMA architecture? You might read over the [Mongo docs for usage on NUMA systems](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/NUMA).

If you are running on a NUMA system, then using numactl to run your daemon with an interleave policy will probably fix your issue.

You can check to see if you have any startup warnings. They will appear in your log while you're booting the daemon, and and you can find them after the fact while the daemon is running, though I don't recall how off the top of my head.

Failing that, you might check your IO operations while making those queries. If I had to guess, you're hitting your disk and not operating with your working set in memory. What do your memory usage stats (free -h and the memory usage metrics from inside the mongo console) look like?

Comment: Not sure how to check if I am using a NUMA system... numactl isn't in my path, if that answers the question. I don't see any startup warnings in the last boot. Just normal replica set negotiation. I can post if you like. I'll check my memory usage and IO and update my post above.

Comment: Your scanned numbers are fine, but mongodb's count operation has to look at every possibly matching document when doing a count, which means that if it's not already in your working set, it'll have to load it off of disk, which can be really slow, especially if you have a lot of IO contention already.